# System of homogeneous linear equations issue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system:

$4x-12y+z=0\\
x-5y-z=0\\
-4x+12y+z=0$

So in matrix form it is
$
        \left(\begin {matrix}
        4 & -12 & 1 \\
        1 & -5 & -1 \\
        -4 & 12 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}\right) 
$.
But if you do the row operation $R_3+R_1 \rightarrow R_3$ you get that $2z=0 \rightarrow z=0$, but the rest doesn't add up: The first row then gives $4x-12y=0$, and the second $x-5y=0$. What does this mean about the solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: $4x-12y=0$ and $x-5y=0$ imply that $x=y=0$ (if not $2=0$ in the field).

Answer (score 1):

It means that the only solutions are $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$. This is clear, because writing $A$ for the matrix, and $v=(x,y,z)^T$, we have the equation
$$
Av=0
$$
for an invertible matrix $A$. Hence $v=A^{-1}(Av)=A^{-1}0=0$. The matrix is invertible because it has full rank (and nonzero determinant $-16$).